# Using NuxtJS (or VueJS) to handle dynamic Django forms?

Tags: jquery, django, forms, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Django site with Bootstrap styling the front-end. The primary function of the site is to show a form, send the form submission to the Django View, and have the view render back a output page based on the information in the form.

The form is pretty dynamic, using jQuery. When one particular dropdown is selected, another field might be disabled.  When another dropdown value is selected, it might unhide a  with extra form fields (conversely, it can re-hide the div if another dropdown value is selected)

One of the main features that I've done is to save all of the form field values into the DB, so that we can use a specific URL to retrieve that exact input/output.  When the inputs are loaded from the database, all of that same jQuery is being run to disable, hide, show different parts of the form.  And it all seems kind of brittle or prone to errors.

**All of that run-up for the actual question:** I am learning about NuxtJS. Is there a specific feature of NuxtJS or development pattern that is going to help me with this dynamic loading of a conditional Django form? Are there specific things I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt will not directly help you with your use case because it mainly brings: SSR + DX goodies + performance + Composition API etc...as shown here: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/

Meanwhile, it may be worth giving a try to a refacto without any jQuery, purely VueJS code + your Django server used as an API.

You will have plenty of possibilities regarding re-usability + dynamic forms down there. It will be more performant, less error prone and far better debuggable thanks to the Vue devtools.

If you are looking for dynamic forms exactly, projects like Formkit could be helpful: https://formkit.com/